# Firebase how to stop Listener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can I stop datasnapshot when my global  boolean is true without waiting ending execution of listener and without limitToFirst. I have some verification in event listener because I need to verify some data and I need make ending in listener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the reference's listener with `removeEventListener`.

For example: `ref.removeEventListener(listener);`

`ref` = Reference you initially set the listener on.

`listener` = The listener (e.g. `this` if called within the listener).

Comment: im sorry but how I can understand when listener is removed?

Comment: after removing listener is working, and is removing many times because it is true value in my verification, why it can be